cast list type value of dictionary column in pandas
I am trying to write a complex type to dynamodb, but getting into the error:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([{"col_w_status": {"ACTIVE":["ABC100-01"],"INACTIVE":["ABC100"]}}])
col_list = ["col_w_status"]

display(df)

for col in col_list:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: dict(x))
    # wr.dynamodb.put_df(df, <tableName>) 

display(df)

Error out with below message:
Unexpected err=TypeError('Unsupported type "<class \'numpy.ndarray\'>" for value "[\'ABC100-01\']"'), type(err)=<class 'TypeError'>

I think nested lambda might work, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Your code is working fine on my side

thanks Sharim. its when you try to write it to the DynamoDB. the put statement to dynamoDB

In the example provided you have lists inside of the dictionary, I think that should work with DynamoDB. I guess instead of list you have numpy arrays. So probably it would work if you convert arrays to Python lists.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([{"col_w_status": {"ACTIVE": np.array(["ABC100-01"]),"INACTIVE": np.array(["ABC100"])}}])
col_list = ["col_w_status"]

display(df)

def convert_to_native_types(row):
    row = dict(row)
    for key in row:
        row[key] = list(row[key])
    return row

for col in col_list:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: convert_to_native_types(x))
    # wr.dynamodb.put_df(df, <tableName>) 

display(df)


this worked like a charm, had to tweak a bit but this is working. thanks
